# Looking for follow set of Grammar in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

$E\rightarrow Tx$ 
$x\rightarrow +E|$empty string
$T\rightarrow (E)|intY$ 
$Y\rightarrow*T|$empty string
I had hard time looking for follow set for $T$ and $Y$. Cause it will trace back to each other. If I do $Y$, then it will trace back to $T$ when $T$ trace back to $Y$. It is a loop. So how do I look for follow set under this circumstance?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it can help you.

> **FOLLOW function**
>
> FOLLOW(A) is defined as the set of terminal symbols that appear
>   immediately to the RHS of A.
>
> 1. for the start symbol S place  in FOLLOW(S).
> 2. if there is a production  $A \to \alpha B\beta$ then everything in FIRST$(\beta)$ without $\epsilon$ is to be placed in FOLLOW(B).
> 3. if there is a production  $A \to \alpha B\beta$ or $A \to \alpha B$ and FIRST$(\beta)=\{\epsilon\}$ then FOLLOW(A)=FOLLOW(B). that means
>      everything in FOLLOW(A) is in FOLLOW(B).

---

$E\to TX \\
X\to+E|\epsilon \\
T\to(E)|intY \\
Y\to*T|\epsilon$

$E\to \underline {\text{T}}\text{X}\tag{ 2}$

FIRST [X]$-\{\epsilon\}$ $\subseteq $ FOLLOW [T]

{+} $\subseteq $FOLLOW [T]

$T\to (\underline{E})\tag{ 1,2}$

FIRST [ ) ]$-\{\epsilon\}$ $\subseteq $ FOLLOW [E]

{),\$} $\subseteq $FOLLOW [E]

---

$E\to \text{T}\underline{\text{X}}\tag{ 3}$

FOLLOW(E) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(X)

$\bullet$ $\epsilon \in FISRT(X) $ so :

FOLLOW(E) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(T)

$X\to \text{+}\underline{\text{E}}\tag{ 3}$

FOLLOW(X) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(E)

$T\to \text{int}\underline{\text{Y}}\tag{ 3}$

FOLLOW(T) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(Y)

$Y\to \text{*}\underline{\text{T}}\tag{ 3}$

FOLLOW(Y) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(T)

---

1. FOLLOW(E) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(X)
2. FOLLOW(X) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(E)

FOLLOW(X) = FOLLOW(E) = $\{),\$\}$

---

1. FOLLOW(T) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(Y)
2. FOLLOW(Y) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(T)

FOLLOW(T) = FOLLOW(Y)

1. {+} $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(T)
2. FOLLOW(E) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(T)

FOLLOW(T) = FOLLOW(Y) = $\{),\$,+\}$

---

<sup>(1)</sup> FOLLOW(A) $\subseteq$ FOLLOW(B)
 : FOLLOW( B ) contains at least the FOLLOW( A ) as a subset.

<sup>(2)</sup>[First and Follow Sets Example](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~jmisurda/teaching/cs1622/handouts/cs1622-first_and_follow.pdf)